# Windows Phone 8 Calculator

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone tell me why this code is breaking and how to correct it in Windows Phone 8 Emulator written in C# showing the error :
An exception of type `System.FormatException` occurred in `mscorlib.ni.dll` but was not handled in user code

```
 private void ClickMeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            First_text.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Second_text.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            BannerTextBlock.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(First_text.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(Second_text.Text));
            First_text.Text = String.Empty;
            Second_text.Text = String.Empty;

        }
```

Comment: Does it show error or throw an Exception?

Comment: Space does not parse to 0 (could be the source of your confusion).

Answer (score 1):

Either `First_text.Text` or `Second_text.Text` don't contain integers so your `Convert.ToInt32` method throws the `FormatException`.

There are various ways to fix it such as validating the textbox whilst the user is typing in a number or place the call in the `Try...Catch` block. Alternatively, just use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead. For example

```
int firstTextBox;
int secondTextBox;

if (Int32.TryParse(First_text.Text, out firstTextBox) && Int32.TryParse(Second_Text.Text, out secondTextBox))
{
    BannerTextBlock.Text = (firstTextBox + secondTextBox).ToString();
}
```